# ICMP - Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)

Tags: linux, ethernet, u-boot, icmp, tcp-ip

I have two Ethernet-wired connected devices. I gave to both of them address from same sub-network. As result I can see second device in arp-table of the first.

```
$ arp -a
? (128.247.77.90) at 10:60:4b:4b:29:50 [ether] on eth0
```

But ping always fails.

```
$ ping 128.247.77.90
PING 128.247.77.90 (128.247.77.90) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 128.247.77.158 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
```

First device is a laptop. It's a host. Second is a tablet under u-boot. 
I have to get a file from a host via TFTP. This protocol fails too because of ICMP. Here are all packets that Wireshark caught.

[image]

What is the reason of this problem?

Comment: It seems a configuration error. The .158 ask who is behind the .90 to give it a reply, but the .90 answers only after 100 seconds

Comment: Can you wireshark what happens when you run tftp on U-Boot?  The network is not active all of the time in U-Boot so pinging from the host will not work in general.

Comment: What kind of cable do you have connecting them? Straight-thru or crossover? Sometimes your situation requires a crossover. Also, use `mii-tool` or `ethtool` on the interfaces (i.e. `ethtool eth0`) to see if there's a link-level connection at all. IP won't work until ethernet does.

Comment: @TomRini, in the picture you can find lines number 20, 22, 32 and 34. That are attempts to use `tftpboot` from device under u-boot.

Comment: @BruceEdiger, `ethtoo eth0` gave me `Link detected: yes`

Comment: Did you configure your firewall to allow the tftp port in and out, and are you running the tftpd server (usually via xinetd)?

Comment: @meuh, I didn't do it by my self. I've only checked it via `netstat -nlp | grep :69`. Default port 69 for TFTP was open. Also server stated right after it was installed. And I did restart server after configuration change `sudo service tftpd-hpa restart`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with configuration of tftpd-hpa server on host. 
According to [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TFTP) the file `/etc/default/tftpd-hpa` must be something like:

```
TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/home/bogdan_liulko/tftp"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure --create"
RUN_DAEMON="yes"
```

My problem was that my file didn't contain `--create` parameter in `TFT_OPTIONS`. And right after all steps from guide were done everything started work properly.